# Error while ejecting Expo Project to Bare React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am currently attempting to eject an app I have created in expo and uploaded to the App Store to bare react native. There are some features I would like to implement that I can not seem to find a solution to using expo and I wold also like to expand my react native knowledge. However, Whenever I run " expo eject" I receive the errors below.

[Eject Expo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7vaQ.png)

```
40991 info lifecycle firebase@7.5.2~postinstall: firebase@7.5.2
```

40992 silly postinstall jest@24.1.0
40993 info lifecycle jest@24.1.0~postinstall: jest@24.1.0
40994 silly postinstall metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.54.0
40995 info lifecycle metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.54.0~postinstall: metro-react-native-babel-preset@0.54.0
40996 silly postinstall react@16.8.3
40997 info lifecycle react@16.8.3~postinstall: react@16.8.3
40998 silly postinstall react-dom@16.8.3
40999 info lifecycle react-dom@16.8.3~postinstall: react-dom@16.8.3
41000 silly postinstall react-native@0.59.10
41001 info lifecycle react-native@0.59.10~postinstall: react-native@0.59.10
41002 silly postinstall react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0
41003 info lifecycle react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0~postinstall: react-native-gesture-handler@1.3.0
41004 silly postinstall react-native-paper@2.16.0
41005 info lifecycle react-native-paper@2.16.0~postinstall: react-native-paper@2.16.0
41006 silly postinstall react-native-reanimated@1.1.0
41007 info lifecycle react-native-reanimated@1.1.0~postinstall: react-native-reanimated@1.1.0
41008 silly postinstall react-native-unimodules@0.5.4
41009 info lifecycle react-native-unimodules@0.5.4~postinstall: react-native-unimodules@0.5.4
41010 verbose lifecycle react-native-unimodules@0.5.4~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
41011 verbose lifecycle react-native-unimodules@0.5.4~postinstall: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/kj/Downloads/obey/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/node_modules/.bin:/Users/kj/Downloads/obey/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
41012 verbose lifecycle react-native-unimodules@0.5.4~postinstall: CWD: /Users/kj/Downloads/obey/node_modules/react-native-unimodules
41013 silly lifecycle react-native-unimodules@0.5.4~postinstall: Args: [ ‘-c’, ‘node ./scripts/postinstall.js’ ]
41014 silly lifecycle react-native-unimodules@0.5.4~postinstall: Returned: code: 0 signal: null
41015 silly postinstall react-native-video@5.0.0
41016 info lifecycle react-native-video@5.0.0~postinstall: react-native-video@5.0.0
41017 silly postinstall react-native-web@0.11.7
41018 info lifecycle react-native-web@0.11.7~postinstall: react-native-web@0.11.7
41019 silly postinstall react-navigation@2.18.3
41020 info lifecycle react-navigation@2.18.3~postinstall: react-navigation@2.18.3
41021 silly postinstall react-test-renderer@16.8.3
41022 info lifecycle react-test-renderer@16.8.3~postinstall: react-test-renderer@16.8.3
41023 silly postinstall sharp@0.23.3
41024 info lifecycle sharp@0.23.3~postinstall: sharp@0.23.3
41025 timing action:postinstall Completed in 2042ms
41026 verbose unlock done using /Users/kj/.npm/_locks/staging-32a5fd08273bf931.lock for /Users/kj/Downloads/obey/node_modules/.staging
41027 timing stage:executeActions Completed in 40882ms
41028 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 3ms
41029 silly install runPostinstallTopLevelLifecycles
41030 silly build obey@0.0.0
41031 info linkStuff obey@0.0.0
41032 silly linkStuff obey@0.0.0 has /Users/kj/Downloads as its parent node_modules
41033 silly install obey@0.0.0
41034 info lifecycle obey@0.0.0~install: obey@0.0.0
41035 silly postinstall obey@0.0.0
41036 info lifecycle obey@0.0.0~postinstall: obey@0.0.0
41037 verbose lifecycle obey@0.0.0~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
41038 verbose lifecycle obey@0.0.0~postinstall: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/kj/Downloads/obey/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/kj/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
41039 verbose lifecycle obey@0.0.0~postinstall: CWD: /Users/kj/Downloads/obey
41040 silly lifecycle obey@0.0.0~postinstall: Args: [ ‘-c’, ‘jetify’ ]
41041 info lifecycle obey@0.0.0~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
41042 verbose stack Error: obey@0.0.0 postinstall: jetify
41042 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
41042 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
41042 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
41042 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
41042 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
41043 verbose pkgid obey@0.0.0
41044 verbose cwd /Users/kj/Downloads/obey
41045 verbose Darwin 19.0.0
41046 verbose argv “/usr/local/bin/node” “/usr/local/bin/npm” “install”
41047 verbose node v10.16.3
41048 verbose npm v6.13.7
41049 error code ELIFECYCLE
41050 error syscall spawn
41051 error file sh
41052 error errno ENOENT
41053 error obey@0.0.0 postinstall: jetify
41053 error spawn ENOENT
41054 error Failed at the obey@0.0.0 postinstall script.
41054 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
41055 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Try installing `jetifier` with your package manager (ie. `npm i jetifier`). Maybe Homebrew on your Mac.

Comment: Yes this worked thank you very much. I was trying npm install --save-dev jetifier before and it didn't work. I dont quite understand the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you haven't installed `jetifier` as a dependency in your `package.json`. From your feedback I can see that you used

```
npm install --save-dev jetifier
```

What this did was install `jetifier` as a *dev* dependency. A dev dependency is a way to use packages during development but prevent them from being used in your production environment. So for example I use a package `mjml` that builds html for emails. I only use it to transpile code, it's not a part of my website, so I use it as a dev dependency.

What you need to do is

```
npm install --save jetifier
```

(I never actually use the `--save` part myself)

This saves it as a dependency you can use in production. When you ejected your app, it was ejecting only production dependencies, but one of your files `require`'d `jetifier`. Hence the error :)

Comment: Thank you very much I now have a better understanding